# cases inside caption gives error: ! Argument of \caption@ydblarg has an extra }

Tags: captions, cases, compilation-error

If I have `cases` inside my caption, the compilation always gives an error

> `Argument of \caption@ydblarg has an extra }.`

I have the following simple code. I tried various solutions such ah as the option `singlelinecheck=false` below, or `\protect` the `cases`, yet nothing works.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics{some-image}
\caption{
  Bla bla notations; additionally,
  $
  \theta(i)= 
  \begin{cases}
      \alpha_i, & i\in A \\
      \beta_i,  & i\in B  
   \end{cases}
   $
   }
\label{fig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need `\protect\begin{cases}` and `\protect\end{cases}`. In LaTeX releases older than 2019-10-01, `\begin` and `\end` are protected by default and your example runs fine.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik LaTeX releases _older_ than 2019-10-01? `:-)`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik isn't it the other way round: "in LaTeX releases **younger** than 2019-10-01"

Comment: Oh, thanks! That is true. But, somehow it doesn't work in my actual code but it works in this toy code. I have to find something else.

Comment: Oops :-) Yes, "newer than" is what I meant. Too early for my brain to function properly :-)

Comment: definitely, it is 2017 :S

Comment: while you could use `\protect` that isn't really the right solution, the reason for a fragile command in a moving argument error like this is the text is being moved (to the list of figures) and (almost certainly) you do not want a mult-line display in that list so use `\caption[something short]{a long thing with cases}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle wonderful! It works like a charm. Thanks a lot!
My caption is very long, so I just add an empty square bracket ``\caption[]{ long text with cases }``

Comment: if you use `\listoffigures` you probably want _something_ i that option, but it's your document.

Comment: I don't really need it at the moment, but later. Good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while you could use `\protect` that isn't really the right solution, the reason for a fragile command in a moving argument error like this is the text is being moved (to the list of figures) and (almost certainly) you do not want a multi-line display in that list so use

```
  \caption[something short]{a long thing with cases}
```

then the full version will not need `\protect` and will appear in the figure, and the short version will appear in the list generated at the start of the document if you use

```
\listoffigures
```